# Bootstrap 4: make a responsive "pixelart" DIV

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm quite a beginner in Bootstrap 4, I've read the documentation carefully but I struggle since a while to make my project utterly responsive.

My HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>SwaggySauron</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>


      <div class="container">
        <div class="swaggysauron">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 offset-9 pix pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-3 purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix cyan"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-3 pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-2 purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix cyan"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix black"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix cyan"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-2 pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix cyan"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix black"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix cyan"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-1 purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix cyan"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix black"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix cyan"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-1 pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-1 purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix cyan"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix purple"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-1 pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-1 pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-3 pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-2 pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-3 pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-4 pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1 pix offset-4 pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
          <div class="col-1 pix pink"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

My CSS :

```
.pink {
border: 3px solid pink;
background-color: pink;
}
.purple {
border: 3px solid purple;
background-color: purple;
}
.cyan {
border: 3px solid #00ffff;
background-color: #00ffff;
}
.black {
border: 3px solid black;
background-color: black;
}

.pix {
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid white;
}

.swaggysauron {
min-width: 380px;
}
```

So my problem here is that I want my `.swaggysauron` DIV, which contains all my colored squares, to keep its initial place on the page instead of disappearing when the screen is too small. I think it's partially responsive, but I have the feeling I'm missing something.

Could you please give me a hint or explain me where's my mistake?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem/question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, if you are planning to go for a complete responsiveness, you must not keep the height of a box fixed. Ultimately you need a square which you can achieve by a little css trick explained [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4z8PT/).

Then you will have to work on the `.col-1` and `swaggysauron` as shown in this [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ttfd665/10/).

```
.col-1{padding:0;}
.swaggysauron {
    width: 380px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The `min-width` specified in `swaggysauron` and `padding` in `.col-1` is a trouble in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanations, it helped me a lot and the result is what I sought. I was reading your last sentence, is there a part missing after "the padding" ?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it was a typo. You may ignore it. I have removed the same in the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you also want the height to be responsive, you can add this CSS for it:

```
html, body, .container, .swaggysauron {
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  height: 8.33%;
}
.col-1, .pix {
  height: 100%;
}
```

It first defines the container as 100% high (of the window, that is), then it applies a height of 1/12 of the overall height (i.e. 8.33%) to the rows to fit all of them into the container (actually it's 1/11, so you could change that to 9.09%), and then it makes sure the .col-1 and .pix elements fill exactly the height of the rows.

Here it is in a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQvRxN